# Links not working with pdf.js

Tags: javascript, pdf, pdf.js

I am trying to enable links in pdf.js using LinkService but I am unable to get the links working

My `main.js` looks like this :

```
const pdfjsLib = require('pdfjs-dist');
const pdfjsLibWeb = require('pdfjs-dist/web/pdf_viewer');
const pdfPath = 'poop2.pdf';

const container = document.getElementById('viewerContainer');
const pdfLinkService = new pdfjsLib.PDFJS.PDFLinkService();

const pdfViewer = new pdfjsLibWeb.PDFJS.PDFViewer({
  container: container,
  linkService: pdfLinkService
});

pdfjsLib.PDFJS.workerSrc = './node_modules/pdfjs-dist/build/pdf.worker.js';
pdfLinkService.setViewer(pdfViewer);

container.addEventListener('pagesinit', function () {
  pdfViewer.currentScaleValue = .7;
});

pdfjsLibWeb.PDFJS.getDocument(pdfPath).then(function (pdfDocument) {
  pdfViewer.setDocument(pdfDocument);
  pdfLinkService.setDocument(pdfDocument, null);
});
```

LinkService is used here similarly : https://github.com/mozilla/pdf.js/blob/master/examples/components/simpleviewer.js